# preference Radio Box Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I've made a prefernce dialog box to choose how to sort my array in the activity.. 
everything is working fine.
first i need to press on Setting which will take me to new activity with button " sorting" then when i press on it, i will get the dialog box. but the problem is that I want the dialog box to appear directly when i press on Setting button...

and in my setting.java i've kept it this way:

```
public class Setting extends PreferenceActivity {

    SharedPreferences sp;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_setting, menu);
        return (super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
    }   
}
```

My `preference.xml` looks like this:

```
<ListPreference android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/listArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
    android:key="type"
    android:title="Sorting!" />
```

values/array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="listArray">
        <item>Name</item>
        <item>Country</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="listValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

What can I do so that when I press on the setting button, my two options will be displayed directly?